# How do I solve org.json.JSONException: Value Required of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, json, backend

I have been trying to send data from an android app into a server using java and php. But I have been stuck at getting an error that says String cannot be converted to JSONObject. Can someone please help me solve this? I am getting the error in the code below

Edit:

```java
private void sendPurchaseDataToServer(PurchaseRecord purchaseRecord) {
    String url = "https://marketstallsmgmt.000webhostapp.com/server/android/crud/postData.php";

    String vendorId = "sampleVendorId";
    String status = "Pending";

    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    try {
        params.put("vendor_id", vendorId);
        params.put("amount", String.valueOf(purchaseRecord.getAmount()));
        params.put("status", status);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    Log.i("PostData: ", String.valueOf(params));

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("ServerResponse", "Response from server: " + response);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Request sent successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Request failed: ", error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Request failed: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
}
```

This is the messages that I receive:

```
2023-08-31 04:50:58.360 16707-16707 PostData:               com.finalproject.siguradosys         I  {"vendor_id":"VEN-001","amount":"0","status":"Pending"}
2023-08-31 04:50:58.360 16707-16707 PostData                com.finalproject.siguradosys         D  Sending purchase data: vendor_id: VEN-001, amount: 0, status: Pending
2023-08-31 04:50:58.697 16707-16707 Error:                  com.finalproject.siguradosys         E  org.json.JSONException: Value Required of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
2023-08-31 04:50:58.697 16707-16707 Request failed:         com.finalproject.siguradosys         D  org.json.JSONException: Value Required of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
2023-08-31 04:50:58.704 16707-16707 Toast                   com.finalproject.siguradosys         V  Toast SHOW: android.widget.Toast@c325de4 view = null pkg: com.finalproject.siguradosys TextToast? true caller: com.finalproject.siguradosys.MainActivity$4.onErrorResponse:141 com.android.volley.Request.deliverError:652 com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run:104 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:938 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:99
```

And this is the error I receive when I try to add `params.toString()`

```
error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to JSONObject
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params.toString(),
```

Any help given would be deeply appreciated! :)

I have tried using Maps and converting them into JSONObject but I still get the same error, I have also tried using StringRequest for it. I get the message "Request sent successfully" when I use StringRequest but the server responds with "Required data not given"

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please put the entire stacktrace in the question.

Comment: Also, what is the `vendorId`, `String.valueOf(purchaseRecord.getAmount())` and `status` values?

Comment: The function is for a clickable button that would send the data that a customer would want to buy

The vendorId is the primary key that would identify the user that logged in into the app, while the amount is the price of the item and the status identifies wether payment is pending or verified

Comment: Try to write a [MRE] with static values, the code are too broad.

Comment: I have added a new snipper, I don't know if that counts as minimal reproducible example though, but I hope it is

Comment: Please put [edit] your question, don't answer.

Comment: Try `JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params.toString(...`.

Comment: It gives me the message ```Required type: JSONObject``` ```Provided: String```

Comment: The message in the question is the **full** stacktrace?

Comment: No it's not but it is in the red line below the ``params.toString()`` and gives the error beforehand. And when I do try to run it, it won't start.

Comment: Please put the entire stacktrace in the question.